# Powershell command for converting the cpu utilization to percentage

Tags: powershell

Get-Process -Name(particular) .* | Format-Table -Property ProcessName,CPU

Get-Process -Name cbft.* | select -Property ProcessName,CPU | Sort-Object CPU -Descending

please help how to convert the CPU utilization to percentage

Please share the PowerShell command for covert CPU utilization to percentage

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$ProcessName = “process_name”
$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$Samples = (Get-Counter “\Process($Processname*)\% Processor 
Time”).CounterSamples
$Samples | Select InstanceName,
@{Name=”CPU %”;Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help its working as expected.